# LVM Resize Failing

Tags: virtualization, filesystems, partition, ubuntu-22.04

**Summary**

I'm attempting to extend partition with LVM on it and its failing... All Googles and Bings have failed so unsure where the issue lies. Here is what's happened so far.

This is a virtual server that was given 8GB of Storage. It hit its cap after the application was applied (and ran out of space during updates and downloads). It only required 4GB more, so applied 4GB (VirtIO). This was detected by the OS and I used fdisk to get VDA3 from 8GB to 12GB, but the LVM will not extend.

**Original Issue (6.2G FULL)**

```
admin@host:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1778
loop1                       7:1    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1738
loop2                       7:2    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop3                       7:3    0  103M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
loop4                       7:4    0 49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
loop5                       7:5    0 49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17950
vda                       252:0    0   12G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0    1M  0 part
├─vda2                    252:2    0  1.8G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0  6.2G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  6.2G  0 lvm  /
```

**Partition**

```
sudo fdisk /dev/vda
command: p
command: d, 3
command: n, 3, #default, #default, n
command: w
```

**New Output (10.2GB on VDA3, not LVM)**

```
admin@host:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1778
loop1                       7:1    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop2                       7:2    0 49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
loop3                       7:3    0 49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17950
loop4                       7:4    0  103M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
loop5                       7:5    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1738
vda                       252:0    0   12G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0    1M  0 part
├─vda2                    252:2    0  1.8G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0 10.2G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  6.2G  0 lvm  /
```

```
admin@host:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <6.25 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1599
  Alloc PE / Size       1599 / <6.25 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               o7ksYe-qxbY-CmVj-A5le-qjG0-IYQt-aQgzlB
```

**Issue**

Here is where I'm stuck. Every guide, post and forum I've been digging into has failed. I'm assuming at some point its supposed to show FREE PE / Size is supposed to be detected, but nothing ever gives up the extra space from the partition.

**Attempts**

```
rebooting |  nothing changes.
partprobe | nothing changes.

resize2fs /dev/vda3 | error:
  - resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
  - resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/vda3
  - Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Note: This is supposed to be the next step after the partition resize (from my guidance when starting this). I also attempted to do it on the LVM and got "The filesystem is already 1637376 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!"

sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv | Error: /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_host_3409_915866633: write error failed: No space left on device

sudo pvresize /dev/vda3
  /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_host_10938_2037765275: write error failed: No space left on device
  0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
```

I'm not new to Linux, but far from a pro... Thanks to anyone in advance that reads and assists :3

// Requested Outputs

```
admin@host:~$ sudo lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <6.25g
```

Comment: Where is your `pvresize`?

Comment: I knew i forgot one... Updated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output from `lvs`? And, did you try `growpart`?

Comment: Added... Unsure what you mean by Grow Part... the partition has 10GB (and the LVM has 6GB). Isn't this whats displayed with lsblk??

Comment: Your pvresize is failing because of lack of space. Free some space on / until pvresize works. Generally its a very bad idea to do anything with no space on / drive.

Comment: Yes, I added 4GB to the vDisk... and it won't resize...